# Just show the JFrame and don't paint anything when add a JPanel to it

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I create a JFrame and a JPanel inside it . I've implemented the paintComponent but it shows nothing , Just a blank JFrame appears
I'm confused with it. 
[The picture when the program runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvjZe.png)

This the JPanel code

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author nguyencong
 */
public class RobotWorld extends JPanel {
    public Robot robot;
    public PlayField field;

    public RobotWorld(Robot robot , PlayField field) {
        super();
        this.robot = robot;
        this.field = field;
        this.setSize(field.width , field.height);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D graphic = (Graphics2D)g;
        graphic.setBackground(field.fill_Color);
        graphic.setColor(robot.color);
        graphic.drawOval(robot.x, robot.y, 4, 4);
    }

}
```

And this is the JFrame code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author nguyencong
 */
public class GameMain extends JFrame {
    public void Game_Start()
    {
        Robot a = new Robot(10, 10, Color.yellow);
        PlayField field = new PlayField(500, 500, Color.BLACK);
        RobotWorld world = new RobotWorld(a, field);
        this.setSize(field.width , field.height);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.add(world);
        world.setBounds(0, 0, world.field.width, world.field.height);
        this.setVisible(true);
        world.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GameMain main = new GameMain();
        main.Game_Start();
    }
}
```

And this is Robot class code

```
import java.awt.Color;

/**
 *
 * @author nguyencong
 */
public class Robot {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Color color;
    public final int speed = 2;
    Robot(int x , int y , Color color)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
    }
    public void move()
    {

    }
}
```

Play Field class code:

```
import java.awt.Color;

/**
 *
 * @author nguyencong
 */
public class PlayField {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public Color fill_Color;
    PlayField(int width , int height , Color fill_Color)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.fill_Color = fill_Color;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with them??

Comment: We can't reproduce your issue without `Robot` and `PlayField`; but `this.setLayout(null);` is never a good idea.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've added that code. I know it's not a good idea but when i don't setLayout, The result is the same

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  I wouldn't say never.  If you want to do absolute positioning (whether you agree with it or not), you should `setLayout(null)`.

Comment: Why are you extending `JFrame`?  You're not overriding anything.  So it's best to use an instance of `JFrame`.

Comment: @ThànhCông, *I know it's not a good idea* - then DON'T use it.  Ask a question that shows you are using "good" programming practices. We are not here to help if you insist on using poor practices because these can easily lead to problems. Spend your time learning good programming practices and less time debugging problems caused by poor practices.

Comment: @camickr thank! I will do better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code 'works' as is (but still has much that needs changing). To prove this, change the robot color to `Color.RED` and increase the size from 4 to 40.

Comment: Oh i forgot that. I thought there’re problems in code

Comment: And he might want to do a fill instead of a draw.  Also, when I ran the code, the background did not appear black.  Just put `setBackground(field.fill_Color);` in your `RobotWorld` constructor.  The `super.paintComponent(g)` will take care of the rest.

Comment: The background makes me think there’re problems with paintComponent.

Comment: @WJS Tks! I will try doing it